# uniq -c unable to count unique lines

Tags: shell, awk, uniq

I am trying to count unique occurrences of numbers in the 3rd column of a text file, a very simple command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = "\t"}; {print $3}' bisulfite_seq_set0_v_set1.tsv | uniq -c
```

which should say something like

```
1 10103
2 2093
3 109
```

but instead puts out nonsense, where the same number is counted multiple times, like

```
 20 1
  1 2
  1 1
  1 2
 14 1
  1 2
```

I've also tried

```
 awk 'BEGIN {FS = "\t"}; {print $3}' bisulfite_seq_set0_v_set1.tsv | sed -e 's/ //g' -e 's/\t//g' | uniq -c
```

I've tried every combination I can think of from the uniq man page.  How can I correctly count the unique occurrences of numbers with uniq?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk`-free version with `cut`, `sort` and `uniq`:

```
cut -f 3 bisulfite_seq_set0_v_set1.tsv | sort | uniq -c
```

`uniq` operates on adjacent matching lines, so the input has to be sorted first.

Answer (score 5):

`uniq -c` counts the contiguous repeats.  To count them all you need to sort it first.  However, with `awk` you don't need to.

```
$ awk '{count[$3]++} END{for(c in count) print count[c], c}' file
```

will do

Comment: just to clarify:

    awk 'BEGIN {FS = "\t"}; {count[$3]++} END{for(c in count) print count[c], c}' bisulfite_seq_set0_v_set1.tsv

Comment: If your fields don't have spaces you don't need to explicitly set FS to tab.  `awk` handles it by default.